# Wrap figure challenge: is it possible in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, floats, wrapfigure, wrap

I am struggling with a problem: I need to have a lot of wrapfig positioned in the top right corner of the page.

I don't want to do a manual tweaking, but a solution similar to `\begin{figure}[t]`, that floats automatically the figure in the top-right corner.

Is it possible to do in LaTeX or it's a software limit? I am asking this because I have tried to figure it out by myself in the past days, without any results.

Thanks a lot for any help, really.

Comment: `figure` is a float and occupies a separate area of the page. The only way to 'wrap' text around such a figure is to include the text inside the `figure` environment. Or to use something like `flowfram` which performs fairly radical surgery on the output routine.

Comment: the answer to (almost) all 'is it possible' questions is: yes. it's much better to word the question as 'how do I do this'. i suggest browsing some of the questions under the [tag:wrapfigure] tag to find what's sure to be a duplicate :) it would also be incredibly useful to see exactly *what* you've tried. could provide an MWE?

Comment: @SeanAllred But `wrapfig` is not a float in the same way as `figure` is. You could do it in some sense (TeX is, as people keep saying, Turing complete) but would it still count as LaTeX? It would, as far as I know, have to use a different output routine.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, even if TeX is a Turing complete language. Having to implemente a new TeX engine to allow that, using TeX as programming language (instead of C) does not count imho :-)

Comment: If it is of any consolation, I started working on it (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271490/compute-depth-of-paragraph) but got distracted.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of your question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271052/package-wrapfig-and-vertical-float-is-it-possible) ?